# bootstrap,Angular2,ionic2: How to use bootstrap3 in ionic2?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular-ui-bootstrap, ng2-bootstrap, ng-bootstrap

I've searched a lot on the internet on how to use bootstrap3 in ionic2,but I'm completely confused as to how exactly should I install it and use it.I've a problem with what I need to include in my index.html file and assets folder.

I'll be thankful if someone can tell me what is the exact difference bootstrap3, ng2 bootstrap, ng-bootstrap and bootstrap4. I know this question might sound very naive but since I'm completely new to ionic2 and angular2 and also bootstrap. I request someone to answer it.

Please let me know which would be the best version for my ionic2 app.

Comment: Why do you need to use bootstrap there? If you want, you can use Ionic2 theme no?

Comment: I know about ionic2 themes.But I'm not able to find any documentation or resources related to it except for the one given on the website.Could you please tell me if there are any open sources available.

Answer (score 1):

I'm also an Ionic2 app developer and I design my apps theme by myself according to the client's preference (i.e. colors and etc.).I have learned how to do that using [**A Guide to Styling an Ionic 2 Application**](https://www.joshmorony.com/a-guide-to-styling-an-ionic-2-application/)  article.Which is a really good article for a beginner.I highly recommend to read it first.If you like to spend a small amount of money then [**Full Ionic 2 App Template**](https://ionicthemes.com/product/ion2fullapp-full-ionic2-app-template) is the best.It is up to date and having very cool Uis.But I didn't purchase it yet.Hope I'll do it in the future.This is the official doc about the [**Theming Ionic Apps**](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/theming/).Now the choice is your hands.Hope this will help to you.Good Luck!